# Does a RegEx Pattern need to be modified to be used with SQL in MySql?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'am trying to write a SELECT-Statement to retrieve a list of Usernames from my Database. My Pattern is: `/placeholder\d+/ig` and I already tested it and can confirm it is working properly. I'am trying to retrieve every Placeholder in the Table.

I also tried to escape the \ after placeholder.

My SQL-Statement is: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (name REGEX '/placeholder\d+/ig')` ... I tried different variations with backticks, etc or `LIKE` instead of `REGEX`but `LIKE`only has `%` and `_` as a Wildcard.

Does my RegEx pattern needs to be modified in order to work with MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most scripting languages, MySQL is not using the PREG library for regular expression matching.

So yes, you need to modify your regex to make it work properly in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP 'placeholder[0-9]+'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP 'placeholder[[:digit:]]+'
```

There are no short-hand character classes like `\d` in MySQL. Also, you do not use the regex-delimeter (`"/../si"` is just `".."` in MySQL)

Read the [documentation on regular expressions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems plausible but I'am still a bit struggling writing the correct statement. It seems like `SELECT * FROM table RLIKE 'placeholder[0-9]+' have to work. Is `WHERE` still needed? I'll reading further in the documentation, but it is a bit hard to understand, since I'am not using MySQL and RegEx on a regular basis.

Comment: @blast68k I've updated my answer to fit the example in your question.

Comment: Cheers, I always tested my statements with PhpMyAdmin, and `REGEX` doesn't seem to work but `RLIKE` did. Thank you! Perfect answer and I'am gained +1 in my Skillist. ;)

Comment: @blast68k do you mind to upvote my answer then, too?

Comment: @blast68k the correct syntax is `REGEXP`, not `REGEX`. `RLIKE` is just a synonym for `REGEXP`, according to the documentation.

Comment: I already did, but maybe I don't have already enough rep. to have some influence. I need to have 15 Reputation points to do some publicty. But I marked your answer as the best answer, of course.

@`REGEXP` vs. `REGEX`, ... you're right, OMG m(.